# Why doesn’t the Archimedean property fall into the $0 = 1$ fallacy?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

While reading about the [$(\epsilon, \delta)$-definition of limit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit), I noticed<sup>*</sup> its reliance on the [Archimedean property](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property), which is also used in the rigorous proof that [$0.999\dotso = 1$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...#Rigorous_proof). *To me*,<sup>†</sup> these two applications of the Archimedean property seem contradictory.

If $\left\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid 0.999\dotso < x < 1\right\} = \varnothing$, and therefore $0.999\dotso = 1$, then why isn’t [any real number equal to all other real numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_fallacy#Division_by_zero)? More precisely, when does a given real number $a$ stops “being itself” and starts “being another” number $b$?

I believe that this is probably related to the concepts of [countable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set) and [uncountable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set) sets, but I can’t quite put my finger on where exactly.

---

<sup>*</sup>And I could be terribly mistaken.

<sup>†</sup>And I emphasize “to me” because otherwise I would be smarter than Cauchy.

Comment: "then why isn’t any real number equal to all other real numbers?" Why **should** that follow? Try to *actually write down* a proof of (say) $0=1$. It's impossible for us to critique an argument that doesn't exist yet. Also, there is no "next" (or "previous") real number; between any two real numbers, there's a third (and this is already true for the rationals, so countability/uncountability has absolutely nothing to do with this).

Comment: I agree with Noah, but maybe $a \neq b$ iff $|a-b| \neq 0$ helps. Bear in mind that, for any rational $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, $\inf_{q < r \in \mathbb{Q}} = q$, so this is not a "problem" exclusive to uncountable sets.

Comment: My suggestion: before anything else, make sure you are *absolutely* clear on what is meant by a number like $0.999\cdots\,$, where the decimal digits never end.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. I'm not completely clear on what you're trying to get at, but it seems to be that you're assuming, at least implicitly, that each real number has an *unique* representation in the decimal system. If so, note that although it's true for most real numbers, some values like integers have $2$ possible representations, e.g., the $1 = 0.999\ldots$ case you specifically mentioned.

Comment: The only way your "If [true thing], then why not [false thing]?" question makes sense is if the two [things] are related. The only way I see $0.999\cdots=1$ could be related to the idea of two different numbers being the same is if you're assuming $0.999\cdots$ and $1$ represent different numbers. Kind of circular, no?

Comment: The Archimedean property is a strong statement applying to two arbitrary numbers. In an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof we get to choose one of the numbers. Maybe the Archimedean property comes into play anyway, but I haven't seen how yet. For the proof of $0.999\ldots=1$ the use is quite explicit.

Comment: $0.\overline{9}~$ does not actually *symbolize* a number.  Instead it represents an (infinite) series that converges to $~1.~$  So, when you read that $$0.\overline{9} = 1,$$ it is to be understood that the LHS of the equation is not referring to an actual number.

Comment: If you want to prove that $0=1$ in the same way that you proved that $0.999\ldots=1$, then you'd first need to prove that $\{x\in\mathbb R\mid0<x<1\}$ is empty. This is where the analogy breaks down; $\{x\in\mathbb R\mid0.999\ldots<x<1\}$ is empty, but $\{x\in\mathbb R\mid0<x<1\}$ is not empty. (For example, $0.5$ belongs to it.)

Answer (score 4):

When you say

> when does a given real number $a$ stops “being itself” and starts “being the next” (or “the previous”) real number $b$?

you seem to think that 0.999.. and 1 are two different real numbers. They are not. They are the same real number.  0.999... and 1 are *two different ways of writing the same number*, in the same way that 1/2 and 2/4 are two different ways of writing the same number.

Comment: See my comment following the original posting.  My comment doesn't imply that I disagree with you.  Instead my comment implies that you are taking *literary license* in referring to $~0.\overline{9}~$ as a *number*.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  An infinite series is a number (if it converges), in the same way that a finite series like 2+3 is a number.

Comment: No.  An infinite series can converge to a number.  That is not the same thing as saying that the infinite series is a number.

Comment: It is exactly the same thing. An infinite series is defined to be equal to the value to which it converges.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see a mention of the Archimedean Property in the $\delta-\epsilon$ link, but they are closely related.

A defining characteristic of the Real Numbers is The Least Upper Bound property. Suppose you have $A\subset R$ and $\exists \alpha \in R| \forall x\in A, x\le \alpha$, then $\alpha$ is an upper bound of A. Further if we also have $\beta \in R | \forall x\in A, x\le \beta, \beta $ is also  an upper bound. We say $\alpha$ is the least upper bound if given $\alpha$ and any other upper bound, e.g. $\beta$, $\alpha < \beta$. The Least Upper Bound Property holds that any non-empty subset of the reals which is bounded above has a least upper bund, aka l.u.b or supremum, $\sup A$.

This property has several consequences. Suppose $\alpha$ is the least upper bound of  $E \subset R$. Then $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists x\in E | \alpha-\epsilon<x<\alpha. $. The implication is, a set's least upper bound can be approximated arbitrarily closely by some element within the set.

The Archimedean also follows. Suppose $p$ is a rational number $x\in R$ and $p<x$. Then $\exists n \in N\ |\ pn>x$. Proof: Let's define $E=\{m\in N| mp<x\}$. We know $1\in E$ since $p<x$, so  $E$ is non-empty. By definition, the set is bounded above by $x$, so it has a least upper bound by the Least Upper Bound Property. Let $n=\sup E$.  It follows $(n+1)p>x$ otherwise $(n+1)\in E$. Thus follows the Archimedean Property from the Least Upper Bound Property.

Consider $0.99999...$ Let $E=\{ x\in R| n\in N, x=\sum _{i=1}^n \frac{9}{10^n}\}$

$0.9 = 1- 1/10$.$

Suppose $\exists n\in N, \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{9}{10^k}=1-1/10^n$

$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{9}{10^k}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{9}{10^k}+\frac{9}{10^{n+1}}=1-1/10^n+\frac{9}{10}\frac{1}{10^n}=1-\frac{1}{10^{n+1}}$

So by Induction, $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{9}{10^i}=1-\frac{1}{10^n}$

$0.9\in E$ and $E$ is bounded above by $1$. By The Least Upper Bound Property, it follows E has a least upper bound.

$|1-(1-1/10^n)|<\epsilon\implies 1/10^n<\epsilon\implies 1/\epsilon<10^n\implies n> 
 \ln(1/\epsilon)/\ln 10$

So $\forall \epsilon>0, n> \ln(1/\epsilon)\implies  |1-(1-1/10^n)|<\epsilon$

$\forall n\in N, 1-\frac{1}{10^{n+1}}>1-\frac{1}{10^n}$, so its increasing.

Every finite sequence of 9's behind the decimal is less than the full sum. The sequence is not greater than 1, and by the $\delta-\epsilon$ argument, it's not less than 1 by any non-zero amount. If it's not greater than 1 and its not less than 1, we say its equal to 1.

Another approach. Let $u=0.9999...$. $10u=9.9999... \implies 10u-9=u\implies u=1$

The arguments never involved divison by zero or the Archimedean property.